# Determining $v(t)$, time taken and distance covered by a plane given $a(v)$. Plus, reason why it is unreasonable.

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, drag

GIVEN PROBLEM: A jet plane landing on an aircraft carrier deploys a parachute to slow itself. The acceleration achieved is $a=-0.005v^2   m/s^2$.

a) If the initial speed of the plane is $60 m/s$ determine $v (t)$.

b) Determine the time required to slow from an initial speed of $60 m/s$ to $14 m/s$ and determine the distance the plane covers on the landing strip during this time.

c) Why is it physically unreasonable that a real jet-plane had such a braking performance described in this problem?

WORKED SOLUTION:

**a)** $\frac{dv}{dt}$$=-0.005v^2$

$\int_{60}^v \frac{dv}{-0.005v^2}$ $=\int_0^t dt$

$\frac{200}{v}-\frac{10}{3}=t$

$v=\frac{600}{3t+10}$ $m/s$

**b)** $\int_{60}^{14} \frac{dv}{-0.005v^2}=\int_0^{t_1} dt$

$\frac{200}{14}-\frac{200}{60}=t_1$

$t_1=\frac{230}{31}$ $s$

$\int_0^x dx = \int_0^{t_1} \frac{600}{3t+10} dt$

$x=200ln(3(\frac{230}{21}+10))-200ln(10)$

$x=291.06m$

**c)** *UNSURE*

PERSONAL QUESTION: Are my procedures and answer correct for part a) and b)? Also, why is it unreasonable for a real jet-plane to undergo such a braking performance? [part c)]

Comment: I think it is unreasonable because the plane would never stop.

As $t \to \infty$ we have $v \to 0$ but $x \to \infty$

Comment: Acceleration is measured in m/s$^2.$  a = -0.005v$^2$m/s$^2$ when v is velocity is measured in much different units.

Comment: @WW1.  As the deceleration from the parachute is decreasing with time his formula seems possible.  Recall that when the plane has landed, breaks are also used to stop the plane.

Comment: @WilliamElliot. So is part a) and b) correct or not? And isn't $a(v) = dv/dt$ or $a(v) = v*dv/dx$ (regarding your first comment)?

Comment: parts a) and b) are correct.

Comment: Regarding units - I think what is intended here is $a=-kv^2$ where $k=0.005 \;m^{-1} $

Comment: @WilliamElliot - once the brakes are applied, the acceleration would no longer be given by $a=-kv^2$

Answer (score 0):

A Nimitz-class carrier has only about 150m in which to land planes.

The parachute method suffers from a rapid drop off in braking force as speed drops. A big enough parachute to stop planes (which land at even higher speeds) in 150m would have a huge initial force: impractically large.

Instead you need something that can provide a high constant force, such as the arresting engines that are attached to the planes via cables and tail hooks.